# scrape table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am to scrape table but they will give data in an `inappropriate way` as you have seen below the output is not correct  this is page link https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20220206/

```
output:
                 0     1         2           3   ...    12     13    14    15
0               Rank  Name    Symbol  Market Cap  ...  None   None  None  None
1               Rank  Name      None        None  ...  None   None  None  None
2               Rank  Name    Symbol  Market Cap  ...  None   None  None  None
3                  1   BTC   Bitcoin         BTC  ...     %  11.85     %  None
4                  2   ETH  Ethereum         ETH  ...     %  17.44     %  None
```

I WANT OUTPUT LIKE THIS

[image]
this is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20220206/')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
content =soup.find_all('div',class_='cmc-table__table-wrapper-outer')
temp=[]
for row in content:
    for up in row.find_all('tr'):
        temp.append([text for text in up.stripped_strings])

df = pd.DataFrame(temp)
print(df)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *inappropriate way*?

Comment: they will provide duplicate entries

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded 20 rows at a time by javascript so you'll have difficulty doing it this way, however the data is all there within JSON in an HTML script tag which you can extract like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import json

r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20220206/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
dirty = soup.find('script',{'id':'__NEXT_DATA__'}).text
clean = json.loads(dirty)

df = pd.json_normalize(clean['props']['initialState']['cryptocurrency']['listingHistorical']['data'])
print(df)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, although it seems NavigableString would be better in this case. So `dirty = soup.find('script',{'id':'__NEXT_DATA__'}).string` instead of `dirty = soup.find('script',{'id':'__NEXT_DATA__'}).text`.

Comment: they give me these error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: @Amen Aziz, have you tried replacing `}).text` with `}).string` ?